# Why GreenDAO doesn't support LIKE operator completely?

Tags: android, greendao

GreenDAO just supported one position of LIKE operator. It was `" LIKE ?"`

I wanna fetch records with variety of this operator. such as, `" LIKE %?"`, `" LIKE ?%"` and `" LIKE %?%"`. but it doesn't supported by GreenDAO.

Also I've used `queryRaw()` and `queryRawCreate()`, unfortunately it didn't work, too.
For example:

> libDocSeriesDao.queryRawCreate(
>           " Where T.Title Like '%?%' Or T.ViewTitle Like '%?%'", aKeyword,
>           aKeyword).listLazy();

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The '%' character must not be part of the query string when you use the '?' character. You can use any combination of % when binding the parameter.

Here is an example how to use LIKE queries (taken from greenDAO's unit tests at https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/commit/788313904fa58a0c8628f6b2e016a4a385f344c6):

```
Query<TestEntity> query = dao.queryBuilder().where(Properties.SimpleString.like("%robot")).build();
TestEntity entity2 = query.uniqueOrThrow();
assertEquals(entity.getId(), entity2.getId());

query.setParameter(0, "green%");
entity2 = query.uniqueOrThrow();
assertEquals(entity.getId(), entity2.getId());

query.setParameter(0, "%enrob%");
entity2 = query.uniqueOrThrow();
assertEquals(entity.getId(), entity2.getId());
```

The same principle is valid for raw queries. For your example, you should do this:

```
libDocSeriesDao.queryRawCreate(" Where T.Title Like ? Or T.ViewTitle Like ?", aKeyword, aKeyword).listLazy();
```

Also, aKeyword must have the % character.

Comment: Thanks @greenrobot for your complete explain. but if I wanna write a queryRawCreate() for work with some tables, What should I do? If you have any solution please update your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Is more easy:

```
dao.queryBuilder().where(Properties.SimpleName.like(name+"%")).list()
```